# Mark a function as a "natural" type guard in TS

Tags: typescript

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcBic4ApUBci4A1mHAO5gCURARjgDYCmqSA3gFCKIBOzUELyRQAngAdmcYIlSIAvIsQByOHQBWzaMsQAyXbMQBCJWBCNGeg8uA4dMJKgDcnAL6dOEBOiiIAHkSk5FQKiGYWLpwwMrhoWDi4ftTUiFw8XmDocCwAdIxwAOaJObZw1C48lVWIAPQ1PAB6APxuHtGIuGKS0v4KSqoaWlA6+r0m8mHmlqM2dogO-ilpiBlZuflFfiU41NzVlXWVzW5AA)

In typescript, the compiler doesn't look into a function to determine type information.

```js
function hasFoo(a: unknown): boolean {
  return typeof a === 'object' && a !== null && 'foo' in a;
}

const x: unknown = null;

if (hasFoo(x)) {
  console.log(x.foo);
          //  ^? const x: unknown
}

if (typeof x === 'object' && x !== null && 'foo' in x) {
  console.log(x.foo)  // x.foo is recognized
}
```

Is it possible to mark `hasFoo` as a "natural" type guard? A "natural" type guard is a function that gives ts compiler as much information for type narrowing as if the calling the function were expanded. For example, if `hasFoo` is a "natural" type guard, then ts compiler would know that `x` has a `foo` property in the first `if` block.

I'm trying to avoid defining a type guard like

```
interface FooHaver {
  foo: unknown;
}

function hasFoo(a: unknown): a is FooHaver {
  return typeof a === 'object' && a !== null && 'foo' in a;
}
```

because it is easy to make mistakes in the type guard. Additionally, given that ts compiler can already resolve type information if the body of `hasFoo` is expanded, it doesn't seem like it should be too difficulty to add more safeguard here.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been requested multiple times see ([#5101](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5101) and [#10734](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10734) tangentially).

It has been deemed  too complex to implement in the general case. doing it right needs to combine control-flow analysis with some sort of data flow analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a feature, but I would appreciate it as well.

I usually implement type guards like below. This gives me increased type safety as it will produce an error if `FooHaver` is to be changed in the future in a way that doesn't satisfy the type guard.

```
interface FooHaver {
  foo: unknown;
}

function hasFoo(a: unknown): a is FooHaver {
  // assert that 'foo' is a valid key of `FooHaver`
  const k: keyof FooHaver = 'foo';
  return typeof a === 'object' && a !== null && k in a;
}
```

Comment: Do you know any way to further improve safety? If the return line gets long, sometimes we may mistype. I'm trying to make use of the `satisfies` keyword but I couldn't come up with a good way...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want type safety, then of course a type guard isn't safe.

What your probably looking for is schema validation that takes an object an return your typed object.

This is what was suggested recently by [Cory House, Matt Pocock, Mateusz Burzyński](https://twitter.com/AndaristRake/status/1758867196757893208) in an X thread.